# Page_Load if statement fires regardless

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, if-statement

Is there any reason why an if then statement would fire regardless:

Its inside my Page_load:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim a As New Clicks
    If Request.QueryString("u") IsNot Nothing Then
        a.Click(Request.QueryString("u"), Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR"), Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT"))
        Response.Redirect(urls.GetURL(Request.QueryString("u")))
    End If
End Sub
```

As a result, I am get 126 instances of a.Click per page load when "u" isnt present?

I have tried to move to other Page Events but same result

Comment: What are you doing here? What is `Clicks`,`a`, `urls` and `urls.GetUrl` and are  you redirecting to the same page?

Comment: The redirect works fine and redirects off to another site u = a parameter met in the database

Comment: Do you know that static in ASP.NET mens that it's shared across all requests(sessions,users)?

Comment: Sorry, i'm a novice Tim, could you explain?

Comment: What I dont understand is if Request.QueryString("u") isnt available, why is it firing anyway and passing parameters such as WebResource, ScriptResource and Empty

Comment: And yet when I run in debug mode off the server, its working fine!

Comment: Since you haven't shown the code i've asked for, i cannot really help. `Static`(shared in VB.NET) means in ASP.NET that these variables are shared across all requests. That means if user1 will access a shared collection and modify a value, it'll be changed also for every other user. Static variable's lifetime is from app-start until unload(in ASP.NET until IIS restarted or the according application pool).
Btw,If `Clicks.a` is static/shared, you don't need to create an instance of `Clicks`.

Comment: clicks a class in a dll which is connected to Linq to SQL Class. Not sure what other code I can show!!

Comment: Just cant understand why the If Statement is true if not Request.QueryString(u) is present

Comment: Maybe I'm asking the question wrong here! All I am asking is why is Request.QuesryString("u") being positive when there is no Querystring("u")?

Comment: Can you show a sample url (without domain of course)? Have you checked witgh debugger that this `if` is entered although `Rquest.QueryString("u") Is Nothing`?

Comment: In debug mode, it runs fine!! No entries created in the dababase and the if statement is passed over successfuly!! Its only in live mode from my PC. Tried Chrome and IE same result!! You can look at Domain, its 2hb.co. Its a URL shortening that I am putting together for the newspaper I work on.

Comment: In the web.config file, anything after / is converted into u=[whatever] using url rewrite 2

Comment: <rewrite>
   <rules>
    <rule name="ShortenURL" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="^([_0-9a-z-]+)"/>
     <conditions>
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
     </conditions>
     <action type="Rewrite" url="default.aspx?u={R:1}"/>
    </rule>
   </rules>
  </rewrite>

Comment: As i've already mentioned, it would be easier to [use the debugger](http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging) to check what happens. Set a breakpoint in `page_load` and in `Clicks.Click`-method.

Comment: Like I said, works as it should, skip right over it

Comment: Is a page_load request of a servervariable causing a domain/something here?

Comment: So I have wrapped the if statement in another if statement to ignore the 5 types of Request.QueryString that were coming through. Seems the rewite was converting each item into u= request. Very confused but workaround seems ok for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a workaround by encasing if statement in the original if statement to capture the unwanted items.

Not the perfect solution but is working